AWSWrangler: ResponseStreamingError: An error occured while reading from response stream
I have a lambda function that reads in ndjson files and converts them to parquet. I've been getting these 3 error messages randomly for a while now but I am not sure how to resolve it. The weird thing is that the files is still being converted to parquet so I don't understand why it's throwing these errors. Any help is appreciated.
My lambda code:
try:
    destination_par_folder_with_bucket = 's3://' + str(processed_bucket) + str(destination_par_folder)
    #print('destination_par_folder_with_bucket -> ', destination_par_folder_with_bucket)
    destination_par_folder_with_partition = str(destination_par_folder_with_bucket) + 'flowstartdate=' + str(date_file_created) +'/'
    #print('destination_par_folder_with_partition -> ', destination_par_folder_with_partition)
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(only_file_name)
       
    if fullstring != None and 'nested' in fullstring:
        print('Flatting nested JSON....')
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket = source_bucket_name, Key = sourcekey)
        ndf=pd.DataFrame()
        data = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in response['Body'].iter_lines())
        running_row = 1
        for row in data:
            jsonObject=json.loads(row)
            flat = flatten_json(jsonObject)
            Temp_df = pd.json_normalize(flat)
            Temp_df.dropna(axis='columns')
            Temp_df=Temp_df.dropna(axis='columns')
            if running_row == 1:
                ndf=pd.json_normalize(flat)
                ndf=ndf.dropna(axis='columns')
                running_row =running_row + 1
            else:
                ndf=pd.concat([ndf,Temp_df])
               
            dfs = ndf
    else:  
        dfs = wr.s3.read_json(path=[s3_json_location], lines=True, orient='records')
       

    # # converting all datatypes to string
    dfs = dfs.astype(str)
       
    print('Writing the files to parquet...')
    wr.s3.to_parquet(df=dfs, path=destination_par_folder_with_partition+filename + '.parquet')
    print('Successfully converted to parquet')
except JSONDecodeError as e:
    print('Error =>', e)
    print('Not a proper json file')  
    copy_source = {'Bucket':source_bucket_name, 'Key':sourcekey}
    destination_err_file = destination_err_folder + 'flowstartdate=' + str(date_file_created) + '/' + json_file;
    s3.copy_object(CopySource = copy_source, Bucket = destination_bucket, Key = destination_err_file)
    print(f'Copying the error file -> {json_file} to the bucket -> {destination_bucket}')

Error 1:
[ERROR] ResponseStreamingError: An error occurred while reading from response stream: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Error 2:
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (SlowDown) when calling the PutObject operation (reached max retries: 5): Please reduce your request rate.

Traceback (most recent call last):
Error 3:
[ERROR] ResponseStreamingError: An error occurred while reading from response stream: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(3406416 bytes read, 2533215 more expected)', IncompleteRead(3406416 bytes read, 2533215 more expected))

